# Is it possible to reload the current lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

What I am trying to able to navigate to a component that is it self.

So example,
I have  component A that calls child component B and I want to be able to simply reload component B, and calling the init function as if it is loading from scratch.

Calling the doInit again is not the effect I want, and doing a force:navigateToComponent to itself won't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can destroy and recreate the component using `component.destroy()` and `createComponent`: https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/dynamically-instantiate-and-destroy-lightning-components-modal-dialog-component/

Comment: its kind of hard to tell what exactly you are doing - normally, you would want to track the 'state' of your component in an attribute, and be able to reset the state of the component.

Comment: @manjit5190, if I were to use the example in that article, after I close the modal (destory the component), the next thing how do I load the component again without actually click on the open modal button?

Comment: @glls, there an example of resetting state of component?

Comment: managing states is a generic programming concept - not related to salesforce - you probably want to do some research on the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload the current component, kind of difficult, because once it destroys itself, its own scripts are gone. The parent can reload it though.

There are various tricks you could use for the parent to reload it... here's one that has worked for me in simple scenarios, not sure if it works when more complex. I'm just using `lightning:input` as an example but that's the spot your child component would occupy.

In the component:

```
<aura:attribute name="array" type="Map[]" default="[{}]" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.array}" var="x">
    <lightning:input name="input1" label="The button will reset this field" />
</aura:iteration>
<lightning:button label="Reset"  onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
```

In the controller:

```
handleClick: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.array", [{}]);
}
```

So basically you have an array containing one empty object. You iterate over it, ignoring its value, and you get one copy of your child component. When you click the button, it replaces the array with another one containing another empty object. Because each new object is a new reference, Lightning does not consider it the "same" item. So it destroys the previous copy of the child and instantiates a new one.

Try typing something into the field and then click Reset. You'll notice it blanks out.

With a child component you can have it throw an event up to the parent, and have the parent reset it on demand.